# Advice: Should I consider [NSManagedObjectContext reset] in low memory conditions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management

Is calling `reset` on my `NSManagedObjectContext` something I should consider doing when I get a low memory warning? It would be a bit difficult to invalidate any pointers to `NSManagedObject`'s that were hanging around, but I'd handle that if its the **right thing to do**!

Or will the **core data** libraries fault out the `NSManagedObject` objects to reduce their **live** memory size?

I should mention that this context is created in the App Delegate and so generally lives for the entire application lifecycle. I also have context's in background threads but these get dealloc'd() when the thread ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Data listens for low memory warnings, and will attempt to take action by clearing caches, faulting objects out where it deems that possible, and so on.

In my opinion it's one of the strong reasons to use Core Data rather than rolling your own object persistence layer.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that was what I had hoped! It can be a bit hard to get detailed info on Core Data (more than just usage samples).

Comment: +1 I agree. Memory management is on of the big advantages of Core Data.

Comment: Unfortunate for me, it doesn't seem to fault out the data when receiving a low memory warning when using an NSFetchedResultsController... the only way to properly clear the cache and fault the objects seems to be via the reset on the managedObjectContext

Comment: @TheCodingArt If it's not faulting out for you, Core Data believes that it can't do so. Have you called `refreshObject:mergeChanges:NO` on objects that you know could be faulted? I know this is doing the work manually to some extent, but it may be better than the nuclear option of `reset`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first route I tried going down and it ended up introducing more issues than it's worth (although I will say I didn't have a proper implementation mechanism in place).